# ASP page with javascript onChange math

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, onchange

I'm trying to get this field (Order Cost) to update when I change the Quantity to reflect the new cost (Qty * Price)

```
<td class="result" align="right">$<Input type="text" maxLength="9" style="text-align:right; width:55px;" align="right" id="OC<%=i %>" value="<%=formatnumber(rstBevInventory("avg_unit_cost"),2)*proposed %>"/></td>
```

It calculates the original total, but when I change the Qty, it calls this Javascript function:

```
function reCalcOrder(i){
    document.getElementById("OC"+i).value = document.getElementById("P"+i).value * document.getElementById("Q"+i).value;
    cost = document.getElementById("OC"+i).value;
    Math.round(cost * 100) / 100;
    document.getElementById("OC"+i).set("value", "cost");
        if (document.getElementById("Q"+i).value < 0){
            document.getElementById("Q"+i).value = 0;
        }
}
```

I get way too many digits, and it seems like this is because of the way Javascript handles multiplication. Is there a way to have the ASP react when the Qty field is changed? Because ASP seems to do the math without issue.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: I haven't seen the DOM object .set() method before. It doesn't work for me either. Did you add it to the prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, using Ajax. But I believe you'll also fix if the problem if you change this line:

```
Math.round(cost * 100) / 100;
```

to

```
cost = Math.round(cost * 100) / 100;
```

Another option is using `Number.prototype.toFixed`:

```
cost = cost.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: That did it, thank you! The one problem now is that if it comes out to something like "36.8" it doesn't add the zero, but that's a minor issue.

Comment: `toFixed` should fix that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: I figured it out...the problem was that cost was coming in as a string, so I had to cast it as a number first. Thanks again for your help!